# ReactJS - newlines lose spaces between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to indent my JSX a little nicer, but I'm losing a blank space between components.  For example

```
<span>Saved: { this.props.fetchedTitle + ' ' }
    <AjaxButton css='btn-danger btn-xs' running={this.props.deleting} onClick={this.props.deleteBook} text='Delete' runningText='Deleting' />{' '}
    <BootstrapButton preset='info-xs' onClick={() => this.expand()}>D</BootstrapButton>
</span>
```

Note the manual space inserted after fetchedTitle and after AjaxButton.  If I cram everything onto one line with spaces between the components, the space is inserted for me.  When I break things into multiple lines, the space is gone, forcing me to manually add it, **even if I manually insert a space before or after the line break**.

Is there a way around this?  (this ui is just a rough prototype / exploratory exercise - eventually there'll probably be a more robust layout, but I would still like to understand why React is responding to the jsx the way it is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
<span>Saved: { this.props.fetchedTitle }&nbsp;
    <AjaxButton css='btn-danger btn-xs' running={this.props.deleting} onClick={this.props.deleteBook} text='Delete' runningText='Deleting' />&nbsp;
    <BootstrapButton preset='info-xs' onClick={() => this.expand()}>D</BootstrapButton>
</span>
```

Comment: Works - I guess it's more like html anyway :)

Comment: Possible you dont need this as React controls the white spaces between components

Answer (score 5):

Another quick trick to add whitespace between components is to use the following:

```
{' '}
```

Per https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1643#issuecomment-45325969

Answer (score 4):

React controls it. [Fiddle example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/128/). So lets i gonna describe two moments around this misunderstanding:

When you a trying to place the white space between two components you have to place this components in a one line like below:

```
  <Parent>
     <Child1 title='Yo'/><Child2 title='Yo'/>
  <Parent>
```

It will be translated with ***whitespace*** like

> Yo Yo

But if you separate components in a different lines

```
<Mother>
  <Child1 title='Yo'/>
  <Child2 title='Yo'/>
</Mother>
```

It will be translated without ***whitespace***

> YoYo

[***React Link is here!***](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/02/20/react-v0.9.html#jsx-whitespace)

I hope it will help you!

Thanks!